# C# MultiView SetActiveView by ID not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, set, multiview, activeview

I'm currently trying to figure out what's wrong with my code:

### Doesn't work

```
if(...){  
    ...  
}else{  
    someVariableAsString = "myValue123";  
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(My3thView_ID_In_MultiViewControl);  
}
```

### Works

```
if(...){  
    ...  
}else{  
    //someVariableAsString = "myValue123";  
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(My3thView_ID_In_MultiViewControl);  
}
```

.. why and any solutions for this?

Comment: is someVariableAsString a property or is it just a variable?

Comment: asp.net?(if yes, add tag please) where in the page (on_load/init/event...?)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it wouldn't matter..  Code is runs in 'onInit'; ASP.NET; someVariableAsString = variable...(just as the name says) ;-)

Comment: The reason it matters (see my answer below) is that if you assign the active view in "init" and then asp.net resets the active view after init and before load then you are always rolling back to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are attempting to act on the INIT rather than the load, the data has not yet been attached at the server.

You should find this review of the life cycle of a web request in ASP.NET useful: [MSDN ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Here is the relevant extract:

> Initialization
>
> ```
>  During page initialization, controls on the page are available and
> ```
>
> each control's UniqueID property is 
>   set. A master page and themes are also
>   applied to the page if applicable. If 
>   the current request is a postback, the
>   postback data has not yet been loaded 
>   and control property values have not 
>   been restored to the values from view 
>   state.
>
> ```
>  Load
>
>  During load, if the current request is a postback, control
> ```
>
> properties are loaded with information
>   recovered from view state and control 
>   state.

Move the code you are trying to execute into (or after) the page load handler (remember to test for IsPostBack) and see if that doesn't get what you want.

**Something New to try:**

try changing your doesn't work to:

```
if(...){  
    ...  
}else{  
    string someVariableAsString = "myValue123";  
    MultiView1.SetActiveView(My3thView_ID_In_MultiViewControl);  
}
```

Comment: Then I need you to be more specific about what it is that is "not working". When you invoke a postback what is your Multiview not doing that is should or what should it be doing that it is not? Please show us the declaration for someVariableAsString. Try wrapping the not working code into a try/catch block and tell us what exception you are getting in the catch.

Comment: Specification: (needs to be done) MultiView is to be set as in the code and variable needs to get value which is set | (actually happens #A) if the variables line is commented, view is changed correctly [but future code is not working properly because of the variable=" null/empty "] |  (actually happens #B) if the variable line is uncommented variable value is set and the view changes [but to wrong one: index = 0; should be index=2; as if the SetActiveView has no effect].

Comment: @Henry, you still need to show us the declaration for the variable `someVariableAsString `. I believe Darren is probably correct, Whatever type you are assigning (if any) to `someVariableAsString` when the value is assigned it is throwing an exception so that the next line is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someVariableAsString is possibly throwing an exception to cause the code not to reach the next line.  Check your variable type.

Comment: Sorry (how stupid of me), I didn't specify that the given value for variable is made (the variable gets the value). And the value is hard-coded. Also to note that the page uses 'PostBack' event(could this be the cause; also if so then why and possible to fix without any majour stabbing :P).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a solution to my case:
I changed `someVariableAsString` to a Property as View.
Created a session variable to Gobal.asax and now I get correct result (one page load later). :-)

but in my case this will do.

Problem solved.

```
onInit{  
m_myVariable;  
myFunction();  
... 
}  

void myFunction(){   
// if clause described up  
}  

public View myVariable  
{  
get { return m_myVariable = Session["myVariableAtSession"] as View; }  
set { m_myVariable = value;  
 Session["myVariableAtSession"] = m_myVariable;  
 }  
}
```